# Why is the function call operator being called in this code?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, operator-overloading

I don't understand why the statement `test()()` is calling the function call operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class test{
public:
    test(){
        cout<<"i am in constructor"<<endl;
    }
    void operator() (){
        cout<<"i am in an overloaded function"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   test t;
   test()();
   return 0;
}
```

output -

```
i am in constructor
i am in constructor
i am in an overloaded function
```

Comment: plan probably was to call `t()`.

Answer (score 5):

> I didn't get why the line `test()()` is calling function call operator?

There are two things happens at this line

```
test()();
^^^^^^   -----> temporary `test` object (1)
      ^^ -----> operator() call         (2)
```

you are creating a temporary (r-value) `test` object (i.e until `test()`) and invoking the `operator()` by the second set of `()`.

This is also equivalent to saying

```
test().operator()();
```

or

```
test{}.operator()();
```

or

```
test{}();
```

Also keep in mind that, this temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the line.
If your intention was to call the `operator()` for `t`, you should have simply

```
t();
```

Comment: I think it's better not mess with value category here. or explain when rvalue would change behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`test()` creates a temporary object, thus calling the constructor, and you call the member operator on this object by adding `()`.

You may have used `t()` to call the member operator on the object `t` previously constructed.

Note: `t` is a functor, means that `t` is an object that can be used as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's literally what that line is

1. A name `test` is contextually a *type-id* here, because it matches name of declared type (note, a name of variable can hide a name of type in C and C++).
2. Parentesis `(`[*argument-list*>]`)` preceded by *type-id* is an expression that creates an object of *type-id*. It results in call to constructor matching *argument-list* if any can be considered.
3. In result expression `test()` returns a temporary object of type `test`
4. Another set of parentheses `(`[*argument-list*>]`)` would try to find an applicable call operator for type `test`, matching that *argument-list* and call it.

An overloaded  operator is a special member-function, whose name consists of keyword `operator` followed by operator's lexem. For call operator that is `operator()`. The line `operator()` is a member function name, but we can just call it by using `()`.

So, an alternate way, in absolutely correct syntax and utterly meaninglessly complex in this case, to write that is:

```
test().test::operator() ();
```

Here we create an object of type `test`, use a member access operator `.`, use a member name `operator()` of superclass's scope `test` (and class name is always a scope of itself in C++ syntax) and use call operator `()` for aforementioned object on the `test::operator()`!

PS: some non-compliant compilers allow to write `test::test().test::operator()()`, but that's ill-formed in standard C++.